# Facebook like button not appearing super irritating

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I am making a website for a local bakery and would like to put a facebook like button on the homepage. I went to developers.facebook and copied and pasted the code. I think in the past, there were several options (iframe etc) but there is only one option now. First you copy the "javascript sdk" in the beginning of your body tag. Then you copy a special div wherever you want. I did this but the like button refuses to render on the screen. It seems like maybe the browser (chrome, firefox, opera) takes some extra time loading it but it just doesn't appear. I think either I'm missing something obvious like I'm not putting it in the right place the css is messing it up or facebook's like button just stopped working. For the record, correct me if I'm wrong but this "likes" any url not just a facebook page, right? If you can help me I will be eternally grateful! Also, are there any other social media buttons besides twitter where you don't actually need to have a  page for it to work? Thanks again!

Comment: Your question is super-irritating!!! No code, no spacing, will someone even like to read it?

Comment: What's the error in Chrome console?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxIrWYLVvpHFfkRTZnR3dXJmUng1TlZoMERXTnFRd2tHWGM0Mko0ajZQUmtLTjRESzU1SDg&usp=sharing

Comment: the code is in the index.html and maybe the css (probably not). Look in the #social-media div

Comment: chrome says failed to load resource file not found

Comment: then it says file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3

Comment: Have you embedded a facebook like button recently? Maybe it's their problem. Could you try it on a dummy html file to test it?

Comment: Figured it out. I was using a local file and facebook only supports it if it's hosted. I was planning on using free hosting by putting it on google drive but I guess I can't do both

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this before many times.

***Usually***, it's a setting on the Facebook page itself.

If you aren't logged in, you can't view the likebox because it has a minimum age set to view it (either 13 or 18) so if it can't confirm your age, it just doesn't show up.

This can be fixed inside the account settings.

https://www.facebook.com/help/376841469095893

Answer (score -1):

This might seem like a strange solution but i would just have a **link** to there facebook page so people can go there and like it themselves. So no extra render time etc.

Here is what i mean:

```css
.social-face {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 200);
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
}
.social-face:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 1px rgb(0, 0, 200);
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="social-face" value="Like us on facebook"/>
And by pressing this link go to there facebook page so people can like it :D
```

I find this a lot easier then using the facebook api :)